# Firefox Add-On , How to go back in the webpage displayed by a panel

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have developed an Addon which implements a widget , the widget holds a panel , and the panel holds a page called display.html.
display.html displays some information I need and a button in the end to go to the next page which holds a page called display2.html.
Now the problem is I want to go back to the previous page whenever I desire . I cannot add anything to display2.html ( Eg a button or a link to go back )
I was wondering is there a way to go back to display.html by right clicking the widget or any-other by using any other event. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are no typical navigation controls in a panel, so you need to provide the back button yourself.